# Rails CSV Import switch string for foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, foreign-keys

I have set up a CSV import for my Ruby App. Everything works fairly well but I'm running into problems when I try to upload a string that then searches for an id to input as the foreign key in the hash. My model for the CSV looks as follows:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :team 
  validates :team_id, presence: true
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
      player_hash = row.to_hash 
      teamname = player_hash[:team] 
      teamhash = Team.where(:name => teamname).first 
      hashid = teamhash.id 
      player_newhash = player_hash.reject!{ |k| k == :team} 
      player_newhash[:team_id] = hashid 
    end 

    Player.create! (player_newhash)
  end 
end
```

I'm sure this is where the problem lies. When trying to execute I get the error:

undefined local variable or method `player_newhash' for #

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

player_newhash is a local variable inside your foreach loop - so your create would need to be in there as well:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :team 
  validates :team_id, presence: true

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
      player_hash = row.to_hash 
      teamname = player_hash[:team] 
      teamhash = Team.where(:name => teamname).first 
      hashid = teamhash.id 
      player_newhash = player_hash.reject!{ |k| k == :team} 
      player_newhash[:team_id] = hashid 
      Player.create!(player_newhash)
    end 
  end 
end
```

BTW - I got that answer by refactoring for a second to find out what was going on... in case it's helpful my version looked like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates :team_id, presence: true

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, :header_converters => :symbol) do |row|
      player_hash = row.to_hash
      player_newhash = player_hash.reject!{ |k| k == :team} 
      player_newhash[:team_id] = find_team(player_hash[:team]).id
      Player.create!(player_newhash)
    end
  end

  private

  def find_team(team_name)
    Team.where(name: team_name).first 
  end
end
```